# XAMPP Use IP address rather than 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Tags: xampp

I will need to access the files on the apache server using an Android phone so using localhost or 127.0.0.1 will not work. I know need to make changes to the httpd-xampp.conf file but amen't sure what changes need to be done.

**EDIT:** I get this screen when type in my IP addy
[image]

This where I think needs to be changed to allow me to use my IP address

```
# Close XAMPP security section here 
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:security))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

Comment: This video on you tube solved my issue: http://youtu.be/ZUAKLUZa-AU

Answer (score 1):

You can change line where it says `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` to `Listen 80`. If you have problem let us know.

Comment: have you find the line in your config file?

Comment: It should be there because I have change it myself and it's working for me

Comment: Its already set to 80. The problem is meant to be with the new security concept XAMPP have added into there apps

Comment: Maybe try to download easyPHP, it's same thing, same Apache local server. Maybe there are not so secured :)

Comment: Any news? I think it should work theway I told you. Maybe yur rouer doesnt have open port. Or firewall is blocking?

Comment: Got it to work had to change the Deny all to Allow all, probably not the most secure way to do it but it works

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is changing the permission in the httpd-xampp.conf file. At the very bottom there should be:

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

I changed `Require local` to `Require all granted`.

Comment: How can i require local and 2 specific IP addresses only?

Answer (score -2):

I changed the the config in `httpd.conf` to listen to `127.0.0.1:81` . And after I accessed the `127.0.0.1:81/xampp`, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Not sure that's answers the question.